# Base system question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a certain number system to the base $N$, we define a sum, $Y$, as given :- $(11)_N+(22)_N+....+([N-1][N+1])_N$, Here $[N-1][N+1]$ denotes the largest two digit number in that number system.

Find the value of $2Y+(10)_N$

The answer given for this problem is $1000$

When I put $N=10$ :- I get the value of $2*Y+10$ as follows:-

$2*[11+22+33+....+99] + 10 = 1000$

But when I put $N=2$ :- I get the value as:-

$2(11)_2 + (10)_2 = 2*3 + 2 = 8$

how are the values coming out to be different ? I know $8$ has a representation of $(1000)_2$ but the value is still $8$, so shouldn't the answer be indeterminable instead of $1000$ ?

Comment: This is not clear. The largest two digit number in base $N$ is $[N-1][N-1]_N$, right?  If $N=10$, the largest two digit number is $99$.

Comment: Also, $8=1000_2$.  It seems clear from the problem statement that you are to evaluate your expression in base $N$, not in base $10$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks !,  I didn't realize that the sum Y has to be in base N , so we would have to convert 8 back to base 2 in that case